# is this gud practice to create thread using runnable thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

is thisgood practice to creating a new thread inside Runnable?

```
public class ExampleThread Implements Runnable{ 

      public void run() {


try {

  //Some functions


 }
  catch (IOException e) {


    }

   new Thread() {
    public void run()   
   // some functions
       }}.start();


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of wrong in this case because ExampleThread is not really a thread, the first try catch block will be executed in the main thread.

Technically speaking, Runnable is just an interface so nothing wrong I guess.